# pdflib - how to Use the end of "..." when the box width is insufficient

Tags: pdflib

I want to put a long textline, such as "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", in a fixed-size box.

```
//already set fontname and fontsize
p.fit_textline("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN",100,500, "boxsize={50 20}  fitmethod=clip showborder");
```

here's the result

[image: actual box]

```
[ABCDEFHG]
```

but i expect it like this

[image: disired box]

```
[ABCD...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this with Textflow. A sample implementation is located in the PDFlib cookbook:
https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/textflow/continue_note_after_text/

The trick is, that you leave at the end of the box a space with `createlastindent={rightindent=" + textwidth + "}`. The space of the `textwidth` is the length of the "...", which you can determine with `p.info_textline()` before.